# Retry mechanism of aws lambda is not working. It is not retrying after timeout exception

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, lambda

I am using a small piece of code to intentionally timeout lambda function

```
import json
import time
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    time.sleep(5)
```

These are my lambda configuration -

[general configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29pD6.png)

[Asynchronous invocation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQW0w.png)

The error I am getting after running this script -

[Error logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/beMML.png)

But it is not retrying after timeout exception.

Comment: If you post images of code or error messages, please also copy/paste or type the actual code/message directly into the post. While images and screenshots can be helpful for providing context, the post should still be clear and useful without them. Please see [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/208273)—the same reasoning applies to error messages as well. Posts in which essential text is only included in images are likely to be closed for not having enough details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem seems to be that your SNS message has expired before the first retry can happen. Lambda retries happen at 1 minute and then a further 2 minutes later. Your configuration expires asynchronous events after 1 minute.

When using the default settings (6h max age, 2 retry attempts, no DLQ), your code works correctly and retries twice before failure.

Comment: and how to increase the time for retry 
can we do so ?

Comment: The retry behavior is documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-async.html) but I don't see any option to configure the 1m/3m windows.

Comment: Maximum age of event – The maximum amount of time Lambda retains an event in the asynchronous event queue, up to 6 hours.
I thought this means like if we invoke the lambda function and it will retry two times in this bandwidth of 6 hours. @jarmod

Comment: The 6hrs relates to how long the event can persist in the event queue. It's designed for the situation where the rate of inbound events causes the Lambda function invocations to be throttled. Also for the case where there's some form of AWS service interruption that might go on for hours.